# How to exclude Windows directory in a FOR /R loop?

Tags: batch-file

I want to echo all files in drive C: but not the files in Windows directory. I can do it with `for /F`, but can't do it with `for /R`.

The problem is the `for /F` is too slow for echo the files while `for /R` is really fast.

```bat
for /F "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b /s c:\*.* ^| find /V "C:\Windows\" ')
```

The above code works, but it take about one hour to echo files in C drive, because it waits for the result of `dir` and then filter them with `find` command.

I tried the blow code with `for /R` but it don't filter Windows directory.

```bat
for /r "c:\" %%a in (* ^| find /V "C:\Windows\" ')
```

Also I tried some code to filter Windows directory after `for /r` something like this:

```bat
for /R (*) do ( echo %%A | findstr /v "C:\windows" > null)
```

But it's slow like `for /F`.

I want a solution to echo all file recursively fast, but not the files in Windows directory.

Comment: You'd need to rethink your task, other than the fact there's absolutely no reason to have a list of all of those files, you should be filtering out several other locations, and probably file types too. In addition, how long do you expect it to take to collect and write to file every single file on a PC, even when excluding those under `\Windows\ `.

Comment: If all you want to do is echo the files, then why any FOR at all? Simply use `dir/b/s c:\*.* | find /V "C:\Windows\"`

Comment: Not just echo...

Comment: @johnalbert, explain the task please; there's absolutely no need to deliberately withhold information, when you expect us not to. The specific task you need to perform is very likely more important that the question you've asked, especially as I see very little need to echo every user accessible file on the system drive.

Answer (score 1):

When you just want to exclude a folder in the root search path then you can use a nested for loop

```bat
@echo off
cd /d C:\

rem Recursively list files inside subfolders, excluding "Windows"
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    if /i not "%%d"=="windows" (
        echo %%d
        dir /b /s "%%d"
    )
)

rem Print the remaining files
dir /b /a:-d
```

Answer (score 0):

The following commented batch file code can be used to output full qualified file names of all non-hidden files on drive C: except Windows folder if the Windows folder is on drive C: at all.

It is also possible to run this batch file with any other folder than `C:` as base folder passed as argument to the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseFolder=C:\"
if not "%~1" == "" set "BaseFolder=%~1"
if not "%BaseFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "BaseFolder=%BaseFolder%\"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if not "!BaseFolder:%SystemRoot%\=!" == "%BaseFolder%" (
    endlocal
    endlocal
    echo Searching in any Windows folder is not done by %~nx0.
    echo/
    pause
    goto EndBatch
)
endlocal

rem Output non-hidden files in base folder.
for %%I in ("%BaseFolder%*") do echo %%I

rem For each folder in base folder except always ignored Windows folder
rem call the subroutine ProcessFolder with full qualified folder name.
for /D %%I in ("%BaseFolder%*") do if /I not "%%I" == "%SystemRoot%" call :ProcessFolder "%%I"

endlocal
goto EndBatch

rem The subroutine ProcessFolder runs a recursive search for all
rem non-hidden files in all folders (including hidden folders)
rem and outputs the full qualified names of all found files.
:ProcessFolder
for /R "%~1" %%J in (*) do echo %%J
goto :EOF

:EndBatch
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham)'s comment, in that you do not need a `For` loop at all for this task.

I would suggest possibly:

```bat
Dir /B/S/A-D C:\*|Find /I /V "C:\Windows\"
```

or using system variables:

```bat
Dir /B/S/A-D %SystemDrive%\*|Find /I /V "%SystemRoot%\"
```

*If you want the output in a file for easier reading/examination just be aware that if your output file is placed within the same drive, it may be included in its own results.*